# Mask URL to different domain/subdomain

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, http-redirect

I've been asked to do something which I've not done before.I dont know where to start but I want to show URL as "myname.com/personalinfo"  whenever user visits "mystudentapp.com/en/mypersonalinfo". is this something possible in IIS? User should feel that they are visiting different website but in the background there are still on the same website.

Can someone please guide/help me how can this be done in IIS or using C# urlrewrite?

Answer (score -1):

You're asking to change something the user's client displays to the user. Using web you don't have any control over that.

Systems should not be designed as that and it implies security problems. Imagine you think you're visiting your bank and in reality you're providing your username and password to my own spoofing site without any possibility to be sure.

What you can do is implement iframe (see http://www.codecouch.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/xssdiagraminitial.gif), though I don't recommend this approach